# python class error str object has no attribute (beginner)

Tags: python-3.x

Hi I'm supposed to create knows and meet functions of this class but it keeps giving me different errors, so how I'm supposed to actually do it? Mostly I would like to know how to implement the knows function so I can finish the rest myself. Here's the code

```
class Person(object):
    '''
    The Person class implements a single person in network of people knowing each other. 
    '''

    def __init__(self, name):
        '''
        initializes a new person with the given name. The person initially has no friends.

        @param name: the name of the person created.
        '''

        self.name   = name
        self.friend = None

    def get_friend(self):
        '''
        Returns the immediate friend of this person.

        @return: the immediate friend (person-object) of this person.
        '''
        return self.friend


    def set_friend(self, friend):
        '''
        Sets the immediate friend of this person.
        '''
        self.friend = friend



    def knows(self, other):
        '''
        Tests if a person is connected to another by a path.

        @param other: the person-object in the other end of the path tested.
        @return: true if the persons are connected, false otherwise.
        '''

        if self.name==None:
            return False
        while self.name.get_friend() != self.name or self.name.get_friend() != None:
            self.name=self.name.get_friend()


        while other.get_friend(other) != other.get_name() or other.get_friend() != None:
            other=other.get_friend()

        if self.get_name() == other.get_name():
            return True
        else:
            return False

        # please implement me


    def meet(self, other):
        '''
        Tries to add a path connecting to persons.

        @param other: the other end of the connection being introduced (person-object).
        @return: true if and only if the persons were not previously connected.
        '''

        # please implement me

        if self.knows(other)==True:
            return False
        else:
            while self.name.get_friend() != self.get_name() or self.get_name() != None:
                self.name = self.get_friend()


            while other.get_friend() != other.get_name() or other.get_friend() != None:
                other=other.get_friend()

            self.name.set_friend(other.get_name)
            return True





    def get_name(self):
        '''
        Returns a string representation of this Person, containing the name of the person.

        @return: the name of the person.
        '''
        return self.name
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran your code, and it executed without an error. My guess is that `other` is a string, and in `meet()` and `knows()`, you call `other.get_friend()`, which is obviously undefined for strings.

```
>>> mystring = ' '
>>> mystring.get_friend()
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'str' object has no attribute 'get_friend'
>>>
```

### In réponse to your comment

The reason you are getting `NoneType` is because you are assigning `other.get_friend()` to other, which assigns `other` to `self.friend`, which you set to `None` in your `__init__`. Try calling `set_friend` **before** you call `other=other.get_friend()`.

Comment: The name part in self.name.get_friend() causes the str no attribute error which is quite clear to me why when I read your example, but if I write it as self.get_friend() it comes up with Nonetype object has no attribute get_friend()